# How to make an apple pie like KFC/McDonalds?

Tags: pie, restaurant-mimicry

I'm trying to figure out to make an apple pie like KFC/McDonalds, something crispy and delicious, such as one of these:

[image: McDonald's]

(above - McDonald's Apple Pie)

[image: KFC]

(above - KFC Apple Pie)

I **do not** want the consistency of a typical homemade or store-bought apple pie, such as the one below:

[image: Apple Pie]

**What is the difference between the first two pies and the last?**  What do I need to know in order to make the crisp, gooey pies in the first two photos?

Comment: Sorry, recipe requests aren't acceptable questions here on Seasoned Advice. Try Googling 'fried apple pies' - there should be lots of recipes online.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Thanks! I was trying to google it, but I failed. I didn't know it's "fried". Thanks again ^_^;

Comment: There isn't much at a fast-food joint that isn't fried! Fried apple pies are actually an old Southern-US thing.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall I've searched a lot but couldn't find "crispy" fried apple pie recipe :(

Comment: Try: http://southernfood.about.com/od/apples/r/bl90416c.htm

Comment: @ElendilTheTall The link you provided seems like what I'm looking for! Can't thank you enough :D

Comment: Hey, it's what we do ;)

Comment: I don't know @Elendil, I think the basic question was answerable as something other than a recipe request, and the answer is simply that he's looking for a southern-style deep-fried apple pie (he didn't know what to look for). I'd upvote that as an answer if you want to submit it.

Comment: Alrighty then...

Comment: Edited to include the photos inline and removed the "recipe" wording; this should be good to stay now.

Comment: @Aaronut Thank you very much, you're a good moderator! ^_^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

McDonald's' *et al* pies are essentially fried pies, a feature of Southern US cooking, adapted for cooking in fast food facilities. A Google search for 'fried apple pie recipes' turns up plenty of results. Try this:

http://southernfood.about.com/od/apples/r/bl90416c.htm

Comment: I completely stopped buying McPies when they stopped frying them.

Comment: Ah, the southern US - we fry *everything*. :)