# What adjustments are needed to change a pie recipe to a turnover recipe?

Tags: baking, substitutions, dough, pie

I want to make turnovers (e.g. a similar product is popular at McDonalds), instead of pie in a pan. Is this simply a matter of making a dumpling-shape with the dough, and then putting the fruit inside, or are there other adjustments I need to make to ensure that the crust and ingredients inside will be baked nicely? With respect to preparation and baking, what is the difference between pie in a pan and a turnover, if any?

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly (been a long time since I had one), the pie found at McDonalds is deep fried. See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14830/how-to-make-an-apple-pie-like-kfc-mcdonalds

Comment: I do not want to duplicate McDonalds pies. I just want to bake the pies in a dumpling-shape, rather than in a pan. Some grocery stores also carry a pie which has this kind of shape.

Comment: @Village I edited your question a bit as I wasn't sure if mean dumpling in a different sense than I presume (a ball of dough hollowed out, rather than a pie crust turned into a pocket for the filling); you can roll back the question if I have altered incorrectly

Comment: The picture you added matches my meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to scale up the thickening agent, if present, should the filling be too runny. Adjustments are not typically necessary to the dough itself. From my experience with turn over or pocket pies in Vegan Pie in the Sky, they rely on the same dough recipe as the other pies (pastry crust style dough), they just get cut into a different format.

Basically speaking it is just a different format but the dough will hold together and brown appropriately. I would recommend baking on a pizza stone, but baking on a cookie sheet (with/out parchment paper) would be equally effective depending on your preference for the bottom.

You will likely follow the same baking instructions depending on the filling. Some recipes may call for a longer cooking time that extends beyond the crusts ability to bake without shielding (probably once you pass the forty minute mark). In this case, although standard pie shields won't work, you can cover the pie with aluminum foil once it has browned lightly.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need any changes. [Others have done it before](http://smittenkitchen.com/2011/10/apple-pie-cookies/) and it works. Just be aware that your ratio of crust to filling will change a lot (much more crust than in a big pie). And take care to seal the seams well.